# no recomposition (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

How can I start recomposition in my buttons?
As far as I understand something in the list itself needs to be changed, how can I go about this?

```
data class KeyData(var text: String, val size: Int, var colour: Color)

val firstRowKeyboard = listOf("Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P")
    .map { text: String -> KeyData(text, 35, Color.White) }.toMutableStateList()

// I tried both ways, but nothing changes

val secondRowKeyboard = "ASDFGHJKL".toCharArray()
    .map { text: Char -> KeyData(text.toString(), 35, Color.White) }.toMutableStateList()
```

and the trigger:

```
    fun checkKeyboard() {
    for (i in 0..9){
        val letter = firstRowKeyboard[i]
        if (letter.text in yellowLetterList){
            firstRowKeyboard[i] = letter.copy(colour = Color.Yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

and my composables:

```
@Composable
fun Keyboard() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
        viewModel.firstRowKeyboard.forEach {
            MyKeyboardButton(it.text, it.size, it.colour)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyKeyboardButton(text: String, width: Int, colour: Color) {

    val buttonColour by remember {
        mutableStateOf(colour)
    }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            viewModel.addLettersToGrid(text)
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(width.dp)
            .height(60.dp)
            .padding(0.dp, 2.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = buttonColour),
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(text = text, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
}
```

the colour is changing in the list, so something is working, however recomposition is never triggered.

If the colour of the KeyData changing isnt enough then would I need to change the text within the list? What is a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting

```
val buttonColour by remember {
    mutableStateOf(colour)
}
```

other than in composition.

Thera are few options you can take

First one is not that good but it still will work

```
  val buttonColour by remember {
        mutableStateOf(colour)
    }

   buttonColour = colour
```

or

```
  val buttonColour by remember(colour) {
        mutableStateOf(colour)
    }
```

And better option is to remove

```
 val buttonColour by remember(colour) {
        mutableStateOf(colour)
    }
```

from MyKeyboardButton

```
@Composable
fun MyKeyboardButton(text: String, width: Int, colour: Color) {


    Button(
        onClick = {
            viewModel.addLettersToGrid(text)
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(width.dp)
            .height(60.dp)
            .padding(0.dp, 2.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = colour),
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(text = text, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
}
```

and change it to a stateless Composable since you pass color from ViewModel.

Comment: yep. Missed that, it's from an earlier version and i forgot to take it out. Pulling my hair out over this thinking I had lost my understanding of compose. Thanks so much!